# jQuery Clone input field, then mirror values

Tags: jquery, forms

I've got a huge form (for a custom product-option builder) with a lot of if/else dependencies. In this form there is a situation where onclick an input field gets cloned and appended to the end of the form.
When the user then edits the cloned field, it should update the original field with it.
I've got it all working, except for the cloning of the values.

This is the code used for cloning;

```
var getQtyInput = $('input.option-qty', getItemParent);
var getQtyOriginal = getQtyInput.attr('id');

$(getQtyInput).clone().attr('id','cloneqty').appendTo('.pub-form-hook');
```

The first variable is the input field element itself, the second is the original ID.
Then I clone the inputfield, update the ID of the cloned field. So far so good.

After this, to clone the values I tried:

```
$('#cloneqty').bind('keypress keyup blur focus', function() {
    $('#'+getQtyOriginal).val($(this).val());
});
```

I select the cloned field by it's new ID and use the variable of the original ID to tie them together. In theory this would work, but it seems like my cloned field isn't picked up in the script.

Whenever I try to log any action on the `#cloneqty` field, I get no response. I think this is because the field is created (cloned) somewhere else in the script, and thus calling it further on in the same script is impossible because it doesn't exist yet.

The cloning is done inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` function. I've tried to get a console.log from the cloned field inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`, on a `jQuery(window).bind("load", function()` and outside any function in the root of the script; no luck so far.

Comment: Youre cloned input is created however its bind event isn't registered as you state this is in document.ready().  You may need to use the overloaded clone() method, see the docs.  As you want to maintain the events.  In addition, something to the effect of this: `$(getQtyInput).clone(true, true).attr('id','cloneqty').appendTo('.pub-form-hook');`

Comment: To no avail, sadly. But I don't really need to maintain the events, for all I care it's a completely new field, just as long as it shows up on the right place at the right time, and mirrors the inputs. But this just gave me an idea, hold on! Thanks Rubber Duck! ;)